# how to use AMD on a Single-page application to load only certain dependency

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amd, singlepage

From what I understand, one benefit of using AMD managing dependencies that get loaded, But in single-page application using require.js all of the dependencies will be loaded.

For example using backbone or something similar, lets say I have the following files

> main.js requires router.js
>   router.js requires view_a.js and view_b.js

router.js renders the views

```
routes: {  
   "view_b":"b",   
   "view_a":"a"  
},  
a:function{  
  showView(new ViewA());  
},   
b:function{  
  showView(new ViewB());  
}
```

Now lets say I go to `example.com/#view_b` which only requires the code in `view_b.js` but doesn't use anything from `view_a.js`. Is there anyway to only loaded or prioritize the loading `view_b.js` using require.js or something similar?

Comment: Why does your router require those view files?

Comment: @Bergi Because the router renders the view.

Comment: But only the one that is needed, doesn't it? So it should require it dynamically

Comment: @Bergi I just added the structure of router.js, since router handles rendering `showView`, It needs to included all of the views

Comment: Why not change `showView(new ViewB())` to `require("view_b", function(constr){ showView(new constr()); })`?

Comment: @Bergi Yep thats what I was looking for. In hindsight its obvious, but I didn't realize that you could have nested require(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't because require.js need all dependencies of your file to be loaded before executing it.

I see two solutions to your problem:

- Create two distinct Backbone.Router, like that you only "require" needed modules for each router (IMHO it's not the best solution)
- Use [require.js optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html), this will combine all your Javascript files into one. Of course you only use it for production, not in development.